# Как запретить скролл боди при открытии попапа?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

без задания overflow: hidden для body

```js
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
  $('.popup').removeClass('popup--active');
})
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background-color: #002638;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: none;
  background-color: rgba(8, 12, 33, 0.44);
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.conditions__inner {
    max-width: 742px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 25px 30px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

.conditions__wrapper {
    max-height: 80vh;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.popup--active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section id="popup--conditions" class="popup popup--conditions popup--active">
    <div class="conditions__inner">
    <buttton>close</buttton>
        <div class="conditions__wrapper">
        text popups
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate unde aperiam asperiores quae, temporibus sed facere id soluta officia culpa earum incidunt totam doloribus natus, rem velit neque facilis saepe.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore alias unde omnis cupiditate, assumenda officiis quae voluptas quis illum veniam totam, temporibus ad maiores ea hic porro iure perferendis explicabo.</p>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам обязательно отключить скрол без помощи overflow:hidden. Можете "блокировать" его с помощью js:

```
function disableScroll() {
    // Get the current page scroll position
    scrollTop = 
    window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrollLeft = 
      window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,

        // if any scroll is attempted,
        // set this to the previous value
        window.onscroll = function() {
            window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
        };
}

function enableScroll() {
    window.onscroll = function() {};
}
```

Но если Вы таким образом хотите что-бы контент не "ездил" когда даете overflow:hidden, то это решается по другому, через исчисление ширини скролбара, и компенсации её через padding-right для body.

Comment: pageYOffset, pageXOffset-deprecated, сегодня -завтра отключат

Comment: @Summersby: откуда такая информация?

Comment: @Андрій Палій,  не хочет работать..

Comment: @UModeL я образно выразился)

Comment: @oksanaТкачик запускала функцию disableScroll при открытии попапа? если-что, можешь сделать пример в jsfiddle

Comment: @Андрій Палій, попутала, вроде работает. А в сафари тоже будет работать? https://jsfiddle.net/3b5hw7f0/

Comment: .@Андрій Палій, попутала, спасибо. вроде работает. А в сафари тоже будет работать? опера, сафари, хром, мозилла    jsfiddle.net/3b5hw7f0

Comment: @oksanaТкачик, да, в Сафари работает, проверил

Comment: @Андрій Палій, но при прокрутке колесиком мыши иногда есть баги.. в хроме.

Comment: @oksanaТкачик можете написать мне в тг ник: like_me4, глянем что у Вас, а то здесь в коментах не очень удобно